# Django - ValidationError "value must be an integer"

Tags: python, django, validation, authentication

I was recycling some of my code from an old project (Django 1.7)
to use it in a new one (Django 1.8), so I get this Error every time I want to Login

[image]

It was working well in Django 1.7

For my models I'm using an AbstractBaseUser

**models.py**

```
class Student(AbstractBaseUser, models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=8, null=False, editable=False, default=id_generator, primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    prom_code = models.CharField(max_length=8, null=False, default="")
    gender = (("M","Male"),("F","Female"),)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=gender, default="M", null=False)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    @property
    def is_superuser(self):
        return False

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return False

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return False

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return False

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        if not self.user_id:
            self.user_id = id_generator()
            while Student.objects.filter(user_id = self.user_id).exists():
                self.user_id = id_generator()

        super(Student, self).save()
```

I made a custom Authentication

**auth_backend.py**

```
from registration_app.models import Student
import md5    


class ClientAuthBackend(object):

    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        try:
            user = Student.objects.get(email=username)
            password_ver = md5.new(password).hexdigest()        
            if user.check_password(password_ver):
                return user
            else:
                print("Entre aqui")
                return None
        except Student.DoesNotExist:
            print("Entre aqui2")
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            user = Student.objects.get(user_id=user_id)
            if user is not None:
                return user
        except Student.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

**views.py**

```
def user_login(request):
    args = {}
    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    username = request.POST.get('email', '')
    password = request.POST.get('password', '')
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        print user.first_name + " ah iniciado session"
        login(request, user) #-----**Here is where i get the problem**-----
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/user/')
    else:
        print("El usuario no existe")

    args['form'] = form
    return render(request, 'user_student/login.html', args)
```

In my command prompt I can actually see the user getting logged in (it brings me the name of the user)

Comment: Did you ever figured this out? I'm having the same problem. I'm pretty sure its because the PK of your User is not a Int. (I'm using UUID).

Comment: @Roger It's Django Session that is causing the error since it's trying to store the pk for the user in the session. You can clear all session from the django shell with `Session.objects.all().delete()`

Answer (score 2):

According to the Django documentation:

> The Django admin is tightly coupled to the Django User object. The
>   best way to deal with this is to create a Django User object for each
>   user that exists for your backend (e.g., in your LDAP directory, your
>   external SQL database, etc.) You can either write a script to do this
>   in advance, or your authenticate method can do it the first time a
>   user logs in.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/

What happens is your having a non *Numeric PK* for the User, and Django doesn't like that. I had the same problem.

As stated in the documentation you should create a *User* for each authentication (if it doesn't exists yet) and change the *get_user* method in your **ClientAuthBackend** back to:

```
def get_user(self, user_id):
    try:
        return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

After I changed that, it all works smooth.

Answer (score 1):

This error comes from your Django Session. I solved it using by

```
- python manage.py shell
```

At the shell, I ran

```
> from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
> Session.objects.all().delete()
```

you can check the created session by running

```
Assuming the userid = '2b1189a188b44ad18c35e113ac6ceead'
s = Session.objects.get(pk='2b1189a188b44ad18c35e113ac6ceead')
```

you can read more about session [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/)

I hope this helps.